# The closure of an interval with respect to a topological basis

Tags: general-topology

Given topological basis: $\{(a,b):a<b,a,b\in \mathbb Z\}$, and I am asked to find closure of $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$. My answer to the two questions are both $[0,1]$. However, the solution says the first should be $(-1,2)$.

My argument is as follows: for any $\epsilon>0$, $1+\epsilon\in(1,2)$, then $[0,1]\cap(1,2)=\emptyset$, therefore $1+\epsilon$ is not a limit point of $[0,1]$, the negative part is similar.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is the space?

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks for your hint, it says "find the closure of the subsets $[0,1]$ of $\mathbb R$", etc. I didn't really understand your point, when we say an interval, shouldn't it be $\mathbb R$?

Comment: No, intervals can be taken in $\Bbb Z$ as well. In any ordered set, actually.

Comment: From topological point of view: given your basis it can be easily shown that $(a, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, b)$ are open as well (being unions of bigger and bigger intervals). Thus $(-\infty, a)\cup (b, \infty)$ are open and so $[a, b]$ are closed (being complements of open sets). In particular $\overline{[a,b]}=[a,b]$ since $[a,b]$ is closed. Everything under assumption that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. In other words the "solution" is wrong. Your $\epsilon$ reasoning is correct as well.

Comment: Also $(-1, 2)$ is not even closed. So it cannot be a closure of anything. Are you sure that was what you were supposed to show?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It doesn't matter what the space is. As long as $(-1,2)\neq [0,1]$ then with given topology it cannot be the closure of $[0,1]$.

Comment: It is a calculation problem. Additionally, the solution says the closure for $(\sqrt 2, \sqrt (10))$ is $(1,4)$...so I am pretty confused

Comment: @freakish: Incidentally, in $\Bbb Z$, $(-1,2)=[0,1]$. But, you know, who cares about the ambient space?

Comment: @AsafKaragila the problem says that $[0,1]$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, or, by specifying the topological basis as $(a,b), a,b\in \mathbb Z$ and the space automatically become $\mathbb Z$? Considering only integers,  $(0,1)$ is then $\emptyset$, and the closure of it is $\emptyset$, but the solution gives $[0,1]$ anyway

Comment: @SimpleMistake Again, $(1,4)$ is not closed in this topology. This is however true for $[1,4]$. That's because $\overline{(x,y)}=\big[\lfloor x\rfloor, \lceil y\rceil\big]$, where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function and $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ is the ceiling function.

Comment: @freakish I got your point, I will get some confirmation about these exercises next.

Comment: Simple Mistake: No, it does not mean that it is a subset of $\Bbb Z$ automatically, nor it means that you are automatically wrong. But I was pointing out that the choice of the ambient space does matter.

Answer (score 0):

$\cup \{(n,n+1): n\in \mathbb Z \land |n|\geq 1\}$ is a union of basic open sets, so it is open, so its complement $[0,1]$ is closed. You are right.